# EntityFramework Db Initialization

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have two dbcontext both connected to the same database.

One of them I initialise using migrations and have created the database.

The other has a database intializer using Database.SetInitializer

```
Database.SetInitializer<ApplicationDbContext>(new ApplicationDbInitializer());


 public class ApplicationDbInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<ApplicationDbContext>//DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<ApplicationDbContext> 
    {
        protected override void Seed(ApplicationDbContext context) {
            InitializeIdentityForEF(context);
            base.Seed(context);
        }
}
```

InitializeIdentityForEF method creates a user with password and role.

My problem is that even though Database.SetInitializer method is getting called on every application run, the method Seed in ApplicationDbInitializer class is not getting called and in turn my tables and default user is not getting generated.

Any help is sincerely appreciated..

Thanks

Comment: Interesting question. Try to provide more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After calling:

```
Database.SetInitializer<ApplicationDbContext>(new ApplicationDbInitializer());
```

You need to call:

```
var context = new ApplicationDbContext();
context.Database.Initialize(true);
```

This is how I did it.

Comment: Do you also have method- public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
        {
            return new ApplicationDbContext();
        } in ApplicationDbContext class

Comment: No, this method doesn't exists in my context. I used the db first approach. Why do you ask?